# CSS - how to make triangle at background?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a triangle in the `background` css. I tried to use `clip-path` :

```
.triangle-col {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

But all the `tooltip` is blocked by the `clip-path`. Any ways that I can make  a triangle and a down-triangle at the `background` without using `clip-path` ?

Comment: may be dup - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362157/how-to-make-a-css-triangle-background-on-a-div-without-using-border-and-image

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49696143/8620333

Answer (score 2):

> The clip-path CSS property creates a clipping region that sets what part of an element should be shown. Parts that are inside the region are shown, while those outside are hidden

So your tooltips are hidden by design.

An alternative to relying on css props, you can use those same polygon techniques with `svg`, and svg has better browser support

```css
.triangle-col {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.triangle-col svg {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-col">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="100 0, 0 200, 200 200"></polygon>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Other orientations:

```css
.triangle-col {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.triangle-col svg {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-col">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="200 100, 0 0, 0 200"></polygon>
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="triangle-col">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0 100, 200 0, 200 200"></polygon>
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="triangle-col">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0 0, 100 200, 200 0"></polygon>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another element to host the triangle and apply `z-index:-1` and `position:absolute` to it so it work like background but doesn't block content which overflow the triangle :

```css
.triangle-col {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position:relative;
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.triangle-background {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute,
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: red;
 z-index: -1;
 clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-col">
   <div class="triangle-background">
   </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Edge only supports clip paths defined by url() :( if OP cares. But don't worry us Edge-rs are getting chromium engine here shortly!!!